# Ionic 2 Picker change event

Tags: angularjs, events, ionic-framework, picker

How do I bind onchange-like event on Ionic's Picker some column? 
I want subscribe to event but I don't know how.

Here is my [Picker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/574Q2.png).

Picker class with source: https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/tree/2.0/src/components/picker

Here is my code:

```
twoColumns() {
        let picker = Picker.create();

        picker.addButton({
            text: 'Отмена',
            role: 'cancel'
        });
        picker.addButton({
            text: 'Готово',
            handler: (data) => {
                console.log(data);
            }
        });

        picker.addColumn({
            name: 'date',
            align: 'left',
            columnWidth: '60%',
            options: [
                { text: 'сегодня', value: 0 },
                { text: 'завтра', value: 1 }
            ]
        });
        picker.addColumn({
            name: 'hours',
            align: 'right',
            columnWidth: '20%',
            options: hours
        });
        picker.addColumn({
            name: 'minutes',
            align: 'right',
            columnWidth: '20%',
            options: minutes
        });

        let columns = picker.getColumns();

        this.nav.present(picker);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I just build a custom picker component.

Check it here https://github.com/raychenfj/ion-multi-picker.

To subscribe the picker change event, you need to subsribe the ioChange.

```
picker.ionChange.subscribe(() => {
  this.validate(picker);
});
```

You can also refer to datetime picker, it is based on the picker component as well.
https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/tree/master/src/components/datetime